# I write a date format yyyy-mm-dd i want to correct it into yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: jodatime

There is an error in my code I wrote date format in yyyy-mm-dd there is a mistake in mm so how to convert it into yyyy-MM-dd

```
Date currentDate = new Date (date);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
    return dateFormat.format(currentDate);

 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd");
    return formatter.parseDateTime(date).getMillis();
  }
```

all the month in 01 how to convert into the correct month

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I wrote date formate in yyyy-mm-dd that is store in database how to get it into the correct format

Comment: You can't, you already lost the information about the months, when you stored minutes. And you shouldn't store date information as strings in a database. Store it as a SQL DATE.

Comment: the date is stored in long in Mongodb